# html5 <video> tag issues with firefox, works in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video

I'm looking for a little more direction, I've researched other similar issues here, but can't make it work for my isssue.

The following code works in Chrome, but not Firefox.  Both browsers are updated to their current versions.

```
<video width="576" height="432" autoplay muted="muted">
<source src="http://files.enjin.com/632721/Video/My_Movie.ogv" type="video/ogv">
<source src="http://files.enjin.com/632721/Video/My_Movie.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://files.enjin.com/632721/Video/My Movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'm not sure what I may be missing to make it work in Firefox.  I've given up on Internet Expoder (and don't care about IE anyways)

The source page is www.reallybadplayers.com  If you want to see how it's implemented in each browser.

Future thanks to any  help I receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mime type of http://files.enjin.com/632721/Video/My_Movie.ogv is binary/octet-stream
The mime type of http://files.enjin.com/632721/Video/My_Movie.webm is also binary/octet-stream

You need to serve the files with the appropriate mime type for them to work. For ogv that's video/ogg, or webm it's video/webm and for mp4 it's video/mp4

How you set the mime type depends on the server you're using to serve the files. You'll need to read the documentation for that server.

Comment: Thanks, your mime-response lead me to a google search on Enjin where I found this forum link:  http://www.enjin.com/forums/m/10826/viewthread/13435229-video-server-issues-mime-type  showing that Enjin is having this issue with all firefox users.